# Среднее арифметическое куууучи чисел

Tags: алгоритм, big-data, java

**Дано:** пару миллиардов int -ов (короче очень много)

**Найти:** их среднее арифметическое (оссобой точности не надо, 1-2 знаков после запятой хватит)

Можно конечно их всех просуммировать в какой-нибудь BigInteger (или собственную реализацию), но нет ли способов покрасивее и попроще :) ?

p.s. в моём случае скорость не играет роли, но вообще хотелось бы увидеть что-нибудь не очень тормознутое

Comment: Это же почти [map-reduce](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce). @argamidon правильно все сказал: итерируем, набиваем буфер, при заполнении буфера производим предварительный подсчет и очищаем буфер. После этого у нас остается некоторое количество подсчетов, по которым можно пройтись ровно той же технологией, если их слишком много.

Comment: превращать во float горздо дешевле, чем в BigInteger.

Comment: @rfq: float не достаточно чтобы хранить результат 32-бит целая часть + 1-2 десятичных цифры после запятой. Можно double использовать. При этом нельзя просто сложить `avg = sum(a[i]/n)`  или `avg += (a[i] - avg)/n` -- [точность может очень быстро убиться и необходимо использовать алгоритм суммирования, который корректирует результат](http://hashcode.ru/questions/370601). Проще использовать long как @VladD предложил: `avg = sum(a[i])/n`

Comment: наверное на мантиссу не тратится всё 32 бита float'a ? на порядок же потратить тоже надо какие-то биты) А сколько на мантиссу float и double отдают?

Comment: @jfs обратите внимание, по той ссылке был знакопеременный ряд. А тут вычисляется среднее арифметическое.

Comment: @PavelMayorov прочтите ссылки внимательно. Алгоритм ищет точную сумму чисел с плавающей точкой (конкретная задача (какие числа на входе, что вы дальше с суммой делаете) не имеет значения).

Answer (score 9):

А в чём проблема? Сумма двух милллиардов `int`'ов поместится в `long` даже если они все равны максимальному значению. А уж если `int`'ы нормальные...

Так что смело суммируйте всё в `long` с детектированием переполнения. И делите на количество.

Comment: сумма `2999999999` `int` (наибольшее кол-во для пары миллиардов) находится в пределах -7e18..7e18 что находится в диапазоне long 9e18. Поэтому переполнение не произойдёт. Если кол-во `int` таково, что можно переполнить `long`, то можно посмотреть насколько BigInteger или double с коррекцией суммы быстрее/медленее чем суммирование long с проверкой `Math.addExact`

Answer (score 6):

Всё ещё проще на самом деле...

> 1. Имеем последовательность чисел x1, x2, x3, x4, x5...
> 2. `k=2;` //количество чисел, текущий шаг
> 3. Находим среднее арифметическое первых двух чисел `r=(x1+x2)/k`.
> 4. Далее не будем постоянно считать суммы, а будем брать следующий множитель для следующего среднего арифметического: `n=(k*r+x3)/((k+1)* r)`. //x3 естественно на каждом шаге меняется на следующий элемент
> 5. Следующее среднее арифметическое: `r=r*n`.
> 6. `k=k+1`
> 7. Повторяем шаги 4..6 для нужного числа чисел.

Answer (score 3):

Предложу свой вариант.
Этот миллиард группируется в какой-то класс. Много объектов. Группируется так, чтобы сумма этой группы нечаянно не превыcила `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. В объект заносится сумма этих чисел и их количество. Сами числа уже не нужны. Далее вычисляется ср. арифметическое для этого объекта. Придётся создать много таких объектов-групп. После разбивания всех входных данных на эти объекты-группы, зная общую сумму и общее количество, делим - и всё.

Очень хорошо, если хоть кто-то понял мой алгоритм.

Comment: +1

Сумму можно и до long.MAX_VALUE добивать, потому как если взять равномерно распределенные случайные int'ы, то сумма, превышающая Integer.MAX_VALUE, очень быстро наберется.

Comment: *"зная общую сумму"* - но как, если она не влезает в Integer.MAX_VALUE? Задача как бы в этом и заключается, вы свели ее к самой себе.

Answer (score 2):

Страдает точность, но переполнение невозможно.

```
avg = 0;
for (int i = 0, n = 1; i < array.length; i++, n++)
    avg = avg * (1 - 1f / n) + (float) array[i] / n;
return avg;
```

А если нам не нужно добавлять новые элементы в среднее арифметическое, мы можем сразу делить каждый элемент на n.

```
avg = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    avg += (float) array[i] / array.length;
return avg;
```

Answer (score 1):

Среднее арифметическое можно искать не складывая все числа разом.
Их можно складывать группами.

Например:

даны числа

```
   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

среднее арифметическое

```
   (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5) / 5 = 3
```

то же самое можно получить, если складывать пересекающимися парами

```
   (1 + 2) / 2 = 1.5
   (2 + 3) / 2 = 2.5
   (3 + 4) / 2 = 3.5
   (4 + 5) / 2 = 4.5
   (1.5 + 2.5) / 2 = 2
   (2.5 + 3.5) / 2 = 3
   (3.5 + 4.5) / 2 = 4
   (2 + 3) / 2 = 2.5
   (3 + 4) / 2 = 3.5
   (2.5 + 3.5) / 2 = 3 // результат
```

или тройками

```
   (1 + 2 + 3) / 3 = 2
   (3 + 4 + 5) / 3 = 4
   (2 + 4) / 2 = 3 // результат
```

Ну или любыми другими количественными группами, главное, чтобы они пересекались, если количество чисел нечетное и не делится по группам ровно. Если же, например, можно сразу разбить все на равные группы, то они могут не пересекаться.

```
   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] -> (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6) / 6 = 3.5

   (1 + 2 + 3) / 3 = 2
   (4 + 5 + 6) / 3 = 5
   (2 + 5) / 2 = 3.5 // результат
```

И, разумеется, можно комбинировать. То есть, на первом уровне, например, складывать парами, на втором тройками.

Группы конечно могут быть и по сто и по тысяче чисел. Но думаю, что это может помочь от переполнения.

Comment: Неплохо. А теперь сложите своим первым способом числа: [0, 0, 4] и сравните с действительностью.